# mysql function split result

Tags: mysql, bash, function

I have written a function in MySQL for get an id with a ip-address.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `get_hwid_with_ipex`(`ipex` VARCHAR(15)) RETURNS int(4) unsigned
BEGIN
    DECLARE hwid INT(4);

    SELECT `id` INTO hwid FROM `hardware` WHERE `ip_external` = ipex;

    RETURN COALESCE(hwid, 'HWID not found');
END
```

In my script I try to get the id like this:

```
id=$(mysql -h$host -u$user -p$password -e "SELECT installscript_systems_test.get_hwid_with_ipex('127.0.0.1');")
mysql -h$host -u$user -p$password -e "INSERT INTO installscript_systems_test.logging_actions (id, hwid, action, status, created, modified) VALUES (NULL, '$id', 'testing the script', 'successful', NOW(), NOW());"
```

My result of $id is :

```
installscript_systems_test.get_hwid_with_ipex('127.0.0.1') 1
```

How can I split that I get only the id (eg 1)?

Comment: are you 100% sure there isn't any space in `installscript_systems_test.get_hwid_with_ipex('127.0.0.1')` ? If so, simple string manipulation should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to

```
id=$(mysql -h$host -u$user -p$password -e "SELECT installscript_systems_test.get_hwid_with_ipex('127.0.0.1') AS '';")
```

And with `AS '';` it works. My result is now `1`

Is it performance?